# log4j2.xml VM options "No log4j2 configuration file found"

Tags: java, intellij-idea, log4j, log4j2

I've used `log4j2` for quite a while and being at classpath it worked fine. But now I decided to move it to `VM options` with `-Dlog4j.configuration=` and it's a disaster. There's tonns of WARN and finally it gives me an error that `No log4j2 configuration file found.`

What has changed with moving it out of project and injecting `log4j2.xml` with VM options at IDEA?

```
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 2 and column 30
log4j:WARN Document root element "configuration", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 2 and column 30
log4j:WARN Document is invalid: no grammar found.
log4j:WARN The <configuration> element has been deprecated.
log4j:WARN Use the <log4j:configuration> element instead.
log4j:WARN Unrecognized element appenders
log4j:WARN Unrecognized element Loggers
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
```

log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration status="WARN">
<appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>

    <File name="File" fileName="logs/error.log"
          immediateFlush="true" append="true">
        <PatternLayout pattern=" \n\n %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </File>

    <RandomAccessFile name="File" fileName="logs/journal.log" immediateFlush="true" append="true">
        <PatternLayout pattern="[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] %msg%n"/>
    </RandomAccessFile>

    <File name="JournalJSON" fileName="logs/journalJSON.log" immediateFlush="true" append="false">
        <JSONLayout complete="true" charset="UTF-8" compact="false" eventEol="false"/>
    </File>

</appenders>

<Loggers>

    <Logger name="com.ottercoder.controller" level="error" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="Error" level="error"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="error"/>
    </Logger>

    <Logger name="com.ottercoder.service" level="info" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="JournalJSON" level="info"/>
        <appender-ref ref="Journal" level="info"/>
        <appender-ref ref="Console" level="info"/>
    </Logger>

    <Root level="warn">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>


</configuration>
```

Comment: Is that the complete xml file? It's broken!

Comment: @Fildor how is that, and why did it worked being at resources folder.

Comment: I cannot tell you. All I can say is that the xml you posted is not valid xml not to speak of a valid log4j configuration xml. Maybe you should have a look at a backup of the file and see if there might have been a copy&paste-mistake or something like that.

Comment: @Fildor haven't loaded it correctly, agree

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-Dlog4j.configuration` is a Log4j 1.2 property. In Log4j 2 you can specify the location of the configuration file with the `-Dlog4j.configurationFile` property.

The `log4j:WARN` output lines are generated by **Log4j-1.2**. This is not good. Please ensure that the log4j-1.2.x.jar is removed from the classpath. (Use the log4j-1.2-api adapter to route calls that use the Log4j 1.2 API to the Log4j 2 implementation.)

There is one Log4j 2 status logger warning: `ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console`: if `log4j.configurationFile` is not specified, Log4j 2 tries to find the configuration file in the classpath. If not found it will print this error. You can fix this by moving the configuration file to a directory that is in the classpath, or by specifying the location of the configuration file with the `-Dlog4j.configurationFile` property.

Finally about the configuration, the com.ottercoder.service Logger has a "Journal" AppenderRef, but no appender with that name is defined in the Appenders section. Similarly for the com.ottercoder.controller Logger which refers to a non-existing "Error" appender. In terms of impact, Log4j 2 will print a warning but will otherwise ignore this.